# :target does not work on my site

Tags: html, css

I found cool css to create lightbox. It uses :target to show lightbox div. I tried in in code pen and it works fine, however on my site it doesn't show anything. I can't find what else in my code is blocking it from showing. Here's the basic code:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#img2" class="image">
    <img src="https://d2d00szk9na1qq.cloudfront.net/Product/2c6b113d-e972-42cc-a2de-f5dcf1c82e95/Images/Large_0297791.jpg">
  </a>

  <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img2">
    <img src="https://d2d00szk9na1qq.cloudfront.net/Product/2c6b113d-e972-42cc-a2de-f5dcf1c82e95/Images/Large_0297791.jpg">
  </a>`
```

**CSS:**

```
.lightbox {
display: none;


position: fixed;
z-index: 999;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8)
}
.lightbox img {
max-width: 90%;
max-height: 80%;
margin-top: 2%;
}

.lightbox:target {
outline: none;
display: block;
}
```

(Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrBrmp)

and here's my site: http://test.fulfeal.co.uk/how-to/  Thanks in advance.

Aleksander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site `url` is been routed. Two ways to solve the issue

1. You are using `wordpress` framework for your site, so go to the wordpress content admin panel and change your `url` type.

**OR**

2. Add below code at the end of your site.

   ```
   <script>
    $(function(){
       $(".image").on("click",function(){
       var image = $(this).attr("href");
       $(image).show();
     });
   });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Something in your site installation is preventing the URL from changing when the hashtag links are clicked.  The :target selector works on the hashtag in the URL.

You will see if you navigate directly to http://test.fulfeal.co.uk/how-to/#img1 the image pops up as expected.  So nothing is wrong with your CSS, the issue is with the URL routing on your site.

In codepen the URL isn't changing because the demo box at the bottom has its own iframe, and it is being updated with the link.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is interesting, because I use hashtag link in scroll button that is working properly. Any advice how I could investigate the routing issue, as I have no idea where to begin?

Comment: Some themes and plugins can rewrite URLs, so I'd start with your plugins.  Particularly if you have something SEO-related, look there first.

Or you can dodge the issue and provide the <a> tags with full links like 'http://test.fulfeal.co.uk/how-to/#img1'

Comment: Full links solution is actually first one I tried but it doesn't work either. Does it mean the issue is somewhere else or still with the URLs?